# Exporting data from Athena to Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

i am trying to export data from Athena (AWS) to Python. Or, is there a way to connect python to Athena just like there is a way to connect python to MySql.

i have around 15gb data in Athena and would like to export and perform further analysis. There needs to be some way to export such a large dataset.

Detailed steps would be appreciated!

Thanks in adavace!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is not actually *stored* in Amazon Athena. Rather, Amazon Athena looks at data that is stored in Amazon S3 and runs queries across it.

Therefore, if you just want the *raw data*, simply copy the files directly from S3. *Simple!*

However, if you wish to **run a query in Amazon Athena and export/manipulate the results**, you can use [Athena — Boto 3 Docs documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html) to call Athena from Python.

Comment: I appreciate your quick response! However, i did try installing boto3, but there were issues installing it. I did go through a lot of other forums regarding the same, but nothing worked out well. It would be a great help if you could help me with the installation :)

Comment: i ran the command: pip install boto3 on my command prompt, which further gives me an error, saying: "jaydebeapi 1.1.1 requires jpype1, which is not installed". Then, i do install jpype1 as well, but there is another error saying that you require Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0, whereas i do have the 14.0 version already installed. i think there is some issue in the path of my files, but i do not know how to resolve it.

Comment: Oh, i solved it! Somehow, there were multiple python versions, which caused the error.

Comment: Can you help me out in another issue: i wish to calculate difference in months between two dates(precisely two columns containing dates only, not time) in Athena. i know how to do it in Python & MySql, but not Athena.

Comment: @DeepankarGarg Please create a new question rather than asking in a comment.